# Server.MapPath() Bizarre Issue

Tags: asp-classic, iis-6

Did anyone observed or dealt with the following issue. I have couple web server (Dev, QA, Staging) all running Windows 2003, IIS 6.
Recently applied an update which uses the following lines of code:

```vb
sLogPath = Server.MapPath("../Templates/" & strFileName)        
set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")       
If fs.FileExists(sLogPath) Then
```

That works fine on all dev systems but as soon as we moved it to QA I am getting an error:

```
The '..' characters are not allowed in the Path parameter for the MapPath method.
Line number xxx
```

Line number is to this line

```vb
sLogPath = Server.MapPath("../Templates/" & strFileName)
```

I tried replacing `Server.MapPath("../Templates/")` with `Server.MapPath("/Templates/")` but that gave me the root of IIS service (C:\InetPub\wwwroot) not the root of my sites. If I attempt to do `Server.MapPath(strFileName)` I am getting once again wrong path to the file because sites are not in IIS root but elsewhere on the drive.

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you haven't got `Enable parent paths` enabled in the ASP application configuration.

Without it you are not permitted to use `..` directory traversing in ASP functions.

[image: Enable Parent Paths - IIS 6]

For more information see [Enable Parent Paths Is Disabled by Default in IIS 6.0](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332117)

---

> **On a side note:**
>
> I tend to avoid the need for Parent Paths simply by configuring websites as separate web site instances in IIS rather than using `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot` which is where the `Default Website` instance resides.
>   Doing this means that code like `Server.MapPath("/")` will be valid and point to the root of your site not the `Default Web Site` instance root.

Comment: unless you need for UNC path or for example, as I have, need to use temp folder outside of your root of the site. In my case it is a log repository. Or just need to read/write to/in folders outside of IIS jurisdiction depend on business needs. In any case, correct solution and no need for side notes.

Comment: @AllBlond That's fine, I added the side note because it was unclear from your question why you need Parent Paths. Too be honest I'm still not clear.